# Is there a way to know, in web3 js, if the connected wallet is using a hardware wallet?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

Title says it all, want to know if user signs with hot wallet or ledger.

Comment: As far as I know, if the user is using a Wallet Extension such as Phantom Wallet to connect their hardware wallet, there is no way to detect whether it is a hardware wallet.

That is because the extension acts as if the connected wallet was a casual extension wallet and therefore your application won't be able to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is using Ledger extension, then yes. Using Solana wallet adapter, you can get the connected wallet's name and match is it "Ledger". Example:

```
const { wallet } = useWallet()

console.log(wallet.adapter.name) // This will print wallet name
```

Wallet adapter documentation: https://solana-labs.github.io/wallet-adapter/

However, if the user is using Ledger connected to let's say Phantom or Solflare, then there is no way to know if the user signed the transaction using hardware wallet or not.